# Mutate Column with Match Against List Variable Values

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I would like to create a new column in my dataframe that corresponds to values in list variables.

My dataframe includes many rows with a 'product names' column.  My intention is to create a new column that allows me to sort products into categories.

Sample code -

```
library(dplyr)

products <- c('Apple', 'orange', 'pear',
          'carrot', 'cabbage',
          'strawberry', 'blueberry')
df <- data.frame(products)

ls <- list(Fruit = c('Apple', 'orange', 'pear'),
       Veg = c('carrot', 'cabbage'),
       Berry = c('strawberry', 'blueberry'))

test <- df %>%
  mutate(category = products %in% ls)
```

I hope that illustrates what I'm trying to do.  By creating the list, I've basically got a register of products and their categories which could change over time.

Is there a solution to this using a list, or am I over-complicating it and not seeing the wood for the trees?

edit - It might help to let you know that I'm working with 100s of products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stack` the list and then join with the data frame:

```
df %>% 
    left_join(stack(ls), by = c('products' = 'values')) %>% 
    rename(category = ind)

#    products category
#1      Apple    Fruit
#2     orange    Fruit
#3       pear    Fruit
#4     carrot      Veg
#5    cabbage      Veg
#6 strawberry    Berry
#7  blueberry    Berry
```

Comment: Instead of stack, there's also reshape2::melt for those who want to stay near the 'verse or have multi-level lists (eg, `reshape2::melt(list(A = list(aa = 1, bb = 2), B = list(cc = 3, dd = 4)))`)

Comment: That's fantastic!  Thankyou @Psidom